# Android ASyncTask not displaying dialog in onPreExecute() when using get() to return value

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to return a value to the main thread from an ASyncTask, so I have used the get() method  so that the main thread waits until the background thread is run.

```
time = mFetchServerDate.execute().get();
```

However in my ASyncTask I have a progress dialog opening in the onPreExecute() method which works as expected when I don't use the get() but when I add it back in it just hangs the app, shows the dialog for a fraction of a second then goes back to the main thread.

```
@Override 
protected void onPreExecute(){
   super.onPreExecute();
   pd = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "", true, false);
}
```

Comment: how can it be shown when you pause the main thread which is responsible for showing dialog..\

Comment: please dont use get() on the UI thread. You could make the progress dialog not cancelable or disable ui elements until the asyncTask finishes.

Comment: Fair enough, I ended up not needed to get the date from the server anyway

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure its has not work if you have used `get()` method for asyncTask .

anyway you can user `this.runOnUiThread(action)`  ; when you need to update UI in thread like AsyncTaks .